# Auto-py-to-exe, blank executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I using my python code with auto-py-to-exe to create an executable.

As a result, I obtain a blank screen app that does nothing.

I have attached the log file from auto-py-to-exe along with some screenshots

Could you please help ?

Thank you in advance

-------------------------------- LOG FILE ----------------------------------------------------

Running auto-py-to-exe v2.18.0

Building directory: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl

Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "C:/Users/gpetrone/OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc/Desktop/SRT/icon.ico" --noupx  "C:/Users/gpetrone/OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc/Desktop/SRT/Speak_v2.0.py"

Recursion Limit is set to 5000

Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon C:/Users/gpetrone/OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc/Desktop/SRT/icon.ico --noupx C:/Users/gpetrone/OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc/Desktop/SRT/Speak_v2.0.py --distpath C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\application --workpath C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\build --specpath C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl

49773 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.10

49780 INFO: Python: 3.6.13 (conda)

49787 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

49795 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\Speak_v2.0.spec

49804 INFO: UPX is not available.

49818 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\gpetrone\OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc\Desktop\SRT']

50078 INFO: checking Analysis

50082 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent

50090 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...

50098 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...

50114 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...

52455 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...

52579 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc

52604 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\python.exe

52799 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\gpetrone\OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc\Desktop\SRT\Speak_v2.0.py

53316 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.

53326 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib'

55993 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-site.py'.

56009 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\fake-modules'

61237 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-six.moves.py'.

66939 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.

67688 INFO: Processing module hooks...

67698 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

67707 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-eel.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

67799 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gooey.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

67961 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-imageio.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

67984 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-imageio_ffmpeg.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

67993 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

68002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

68278 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

68293 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

68302 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

68310 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

68318 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

68400 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

68832 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...

74461 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.

74475 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.

74482 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['greenlet', 'cffi', 'setuptools']

75263 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75286 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75293 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_resources.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75301 WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!

75307 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75358 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75395 WARNING: Conda distribution 'numpy', dependency of 'numpy', was not found. If you installed this distribution with pip then you may ignore this warning.

75429 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'

75445 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75455 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75833 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

75854 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76396 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76424 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76697 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76721 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76745 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

76756 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

77151 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-win32com.py'.

77229 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!

77238 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!

77250 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

77415 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78018 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78114 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78127 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78318 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78342 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78361 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78502 INFO: checking Tree

78518 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent

78530 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc

78597 INFO: checking Tree

78606 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent

78613 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc

78699 INFO: checking Tree

78713 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent

78722 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc

78738 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

78754 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.objectify.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

78762 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...

78824 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs

78915 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...

78939 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'

78947 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'

78958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_inspect.py'

78969 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'

78982 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'

79009 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries

79605 INFO: Looking for eggs

79629 INFO: Using Python library C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\python36.dll

79637 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]

79660 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\build\Speak_v2.0\warn-Speak_v2.0.txt

79847 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\build\Speak_v2.0\xref-Speak_v2.0.html

79915 INFO: checking PYZ

79926 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent

79934 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\build\Speak_v2.0\PYZ-00.pyz

81378 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\build\Speak_v2.0\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.

81427 INFO: checking PKG

81439 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent

81451 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Speak_v2.0.pkg

102239 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Speak_v2.0.pkg completed successfully.

102295 INFO: Bootloader C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\new\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe

102311 INFO: checking EXE

102342 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent

102364 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc

102380 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\application\Speak_v2.0.exe.notanexecutable

102408 INFO: Copying icon to EXE

102418 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\Users\gpetrone\OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc\Desktop\SRT\icon.ico']

102430 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 34 bytes

102465 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 4264 bytes

102480 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 16936 bytes

102496 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE

102527 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE

102566 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpq77x2htl\application\Speak_v2.0.exe.notanexecutable

103106 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0

103121 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE

123861 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\gpetrone\OneDrive - ANSYS, Inc\Desktop\SRT\output

Complete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install and try using pyinstaller.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

To generate an python EXE.
Use the following 2 commands.
To generate spec (this is a one time job).
The file will help you in configuration

```
pyi-makespec --onefile yourscript.py
```

Generate EXE file.

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourscript.spec
```

The exe file generated will be in the dist folder