# .exe doesn't work after converting from .py with auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

everyone!
I'm new in programing.

I faced the problem that my .exe doesn't work after I converted it from .py file.
File is prety simple. It's load data from excel to scv using pandas and time just for the logs.

I haven't caught any errors during the convrting proccess, but when I open .exe, it shows only terminal with flickering cursor.
[image: code example]

I also add "--exclude-module" for other instaled modules which wasn't used in my program. It helped decrise size of the end .exe file, but still it doesn't work.
[image: excluded modules]

If you have any ideas, please share with me.

I found the solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626038/17618130 Basicly it offers to use raw Pyinstaller without auto-py-to-exe But i'v found that it is still working only on windows server, but don't work on Windows 10. So I still need help(

Comment: I found the solution in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626038/17618130
Basicly it offers to use raw Pyinstaller without auto-py-to-exe

But i'v found that it is still working only on windows server, but don't work on Windows 10.

Comment: If this is part of the research you have done before asking the question, it will be helpful for future readers of the question, if you mention this in the question itself as well(perhaps by editing it) :). Thanks!